# Амперсанд, метод split

Tags: javascript

Необходимо разделить строки методом split(), но символом амперсанд(&), понятно, что просто это символ не ввести, как же быть? 
Как я пробовал:

```
 str=str.toString().split(/&/);
 str=str.toString().split('&');
 str=str.toString().split('&amp');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = "one&two"
var parts = str.split('&');
console.log(parts);
```

Comment: Понял, ошибка значит не здесь, спасибо